# Creating a bunch of objects in C++

Tags: c++

I have a quite simple situation I don't know how to resolve :
I am parsing a file with addresses (city, street and street number), and have the following class :

```
class Address
{
  std::string city;
  std::string street;
  std::string number;
};
```

I would like to create an object for each address I find in the file, but I can't know how many there are since the file can change. Is there a way to create an Array of objects ; or any more suitable solution ?

NOTE : Parser works fine, all there is to do is to set the values in the objects.

Comment: use a `std::vector<Address>`. It is made exactly for this (need a bunch of objects but I do not know how many of them)

Comment: `std::vector` is the last container to consider. Only use it if you need both random access **and** contiguous memory layout. First option should be `std::list`. If that doesn't suffice, go with `std::deque`.

Comment: how the addresses are seperated? each line is address?

Comment: @IInspectable Out of curiosity, what would you suggest for only contiguous memory layout? I don't think there is anything except `array`.

Comment: @IInspectable That sounds like the worst idea ever. There is rarely a good reason not to use an `std::vector`, and when there is, the best alternative is hardly ever `std::list`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: *"I can't know how many there are"* - that's all the reason I need to **not** use a `std::vector`. Or would you be all thrilled about having data copied around over and over and over again? Memory fragmentation still is an issue with C++. Now honestly, from the question, what feature do you need that a `std::list` doesn't provide?

Comment: @IInspectable If profiling showed copying blocks of data (with efficient move constructors and assignment operators) were more of an issue element access and allocation, then I would consider trying out `std::deque`. But are you thrilled by dynamically allocating every single node of the list?

Comment: @IInspectable This copying you talk about takes place far less than you probably think it does (although I would be surprised you wouldn't know it, certainly it's not over-and-over). `vector` is also guaranteed to be cache friendly (as much as the value type allows it) while `deque` is not. It all depends, and the matter is not black and white as you stance seems to be.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You failed to address the question I asked: Which feature do you find missing from `std::list`, given the question that was asked? And yes, I do value those fine non-throwing operations of `std::list`, in addition to those O(1) complexity members.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't need to find missing features in `std::list` because there is a priory no good reason to use it. But, vector has less space overhead, more efficient traversal of elements, requires less dynamic allocations, and is more cache friendly (although in this case some of that advantage is lost because the strings store their data on the free store.)

Comment: @juanchopanza: *"less dynamic allocations"* Consider one `push_back` beyond the `capacity()`, and this may likely be wrong already. Plus, as you point out, the objects essentially consist of pointers only (or a pointer and a size_t), so having a cache friendly container buys you nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use std::vector for such purpose: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

```
#include <vector>

struct Address
{
  std::string city;
  std::string street;
  std::string number;
};

bool parseAddress(Address& address)
{
    //TODO: implement
    //TODO: return "true" if another address has been successfully parsed
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Address> addresses;
    Address current;
    while(parseAddress(current))
    {
        addresses.push_back(current);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Serge but rather than use the parser directly define an input operator.

```
struct Address
{
  std::string city;
  std::string street;
  std::string number;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Address& address) {
      return parseAddress(in, address);
  }
};

std::istream& parseAddress(std::istream& in, Address& address)
{
    //TODO: implement
    //TODO: return stream.
    //          If the parse failed.
    //                Then set the bad bit on the stream.
}
int main()
{
    std::ifstream          file("address.txt");
    std::vector<Address>   addresses(std::istream_iterator<Address>(file),
                                     std::istream_iterator<Address>());
}
```